# Generate Activiti BAR file from command prompt

Tags: activiti

A deployment bar file for Activiti can be created by going to Manage->Deployments->Upload new on the Activiti explorer. How can I generate the bar file from the command line. I plan to set up an automated build to generate the binary file and save it in a binary repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see there is no official Maven plugin for the generation of the bar file in Activiti. However one can replicate the logic in Activiti designer for creation of the bar file using logic found [DeploymentMenu class run method](https://github.com/Activiti/Activiti-Designer/blob/master/org.activiti.designer.gui/src/main/java/org/activiti/designer/popupmenus/DeploymentMenu.java). This logic can be replicated in a script or a custom Maven plugin and then triggered automatically from the Continuous Integration environment when I change the processes.